# Gradle: how to propagate compileOnly dependencies?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

```
sourceSets {
   foo
   bar
}

dependencies {
    fooCompileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'

    barImplementation sourceSets.foo.output + configurations.fooCompileOnly
}
```

foo has dependencies on servlet, and bar has dependencies on foo and servlet. How to add the same servlet for the foo to the bar compile classpath?

```
Resolving dependency configuration 'fooCompileOnly' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
```